# Copy to clipboard keeps copying last item in the array regardless of which button I click on

Tags: javascript, clipboard

I'm trying to copy HTML code to the clipboard similar to how Bootstrap does it on their website. Each code snippet (.html-code) has a button (.copy-btn) with an event listener that copies the code on click. The issue is no matter which button I click, it will always copy the very last code snippet in the htmlCodes array. I did forEach loops for both the code snippets and buttons, but how would I pair each button to its respective code snippet using vanilla js?

```js
const htmlCodes = document.querySelectorAll(".html-code");
const copyBtns = document.querySelectorAll(".copy-btn");

copyBtns.forEach(copyBtn =>
  copyBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    htmlCodes.forEach(htmlCode => navigator.clipboard.writeText(htmlCode.value));
  }))
```

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="widget-wrapper">
   <h2>Heading</h2>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus ad est consectetur sunt eveniet ab corporis. Voluptates exercitationem dolorem aspernatur magnam sapiente cumque, nisi adipisci hic, laborum, porro iste rerum.</p>
   <div class="visual-ex"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x600" alt=""></div>
   <div class="code-snippet">
      <pre><code>
                  <textarea class="html-code"><div class="example-1">
</div></textarea></code></pre>
   </div>
   <button class="copy-btn">Copy code</button>
</section>

<section class="widget-wrapper">
   <h2>Heading</h2>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus ad est consectetur sunt eveniet ab corporis. Voluptates exercitationem dolorem aspernatur magnam sapiente cumque, nisi adipisci hic, laborum, porro iste rerum.</p>
   <div class="visual-ex"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x600" alt=""></div>
   <div class="code-snippet">
      <pre><code>
                  <textarea class="html-code"><div class="example-2">
</div></textarea></code></pre>
   </div>
   <button class="copy-btn">Copy code</button>
</section>

<section class="widget-wrapper">
   <h2>Heading</h2>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus ad est consectetur sunt eveniet ab corporis. Voluptates exercitationem dolorem aspernatur magnam sapiente cumque, nisi adipisci hic, laborum, porro iste rerum.</p>
   <div class="visual-ex"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x600" alt=""></div>
   <div class="code-snippet">
      <pre><code>
                  <textarea class="html-code"><div class="example-3">
</div></textarea></code></pre>
   </div>
   <button class="copy-btn">Copy code</button>
</section>
```

**update: I've included the html below.

Comment: Depends on your html structure.  If you have a number of divs (say) that each contain one button and one snippet, you could figure out which snippet by taking the clicked button and finding its parent div, then look inside that parent div for a snippet element.

Comment: You will need to post an example HTML of a single section where you have the html-code and copy-btn elements. You should be able to get the respective code via the related button but it all depends on your HTML.

Comment: `forEach` calls the function given to it once for each element in the collection. `navigator.clipboard.writeText` replaces what's in the clipboard with the text given to it. So, it writes the first one, then immediately discards it and writes the second one, then immediately discards it and writes the next one, etc., until the last one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this could work:

```
const htmlCodes = document.querySelectorAll(".html-code");
const copyBtns = document.querySelectorAll(".copy-btn");

copyBtns.forEach((copyBtn, index) =>
    copyBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
navigator.clipboard.writeText(htmlCodes[index].value);
  }
))
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the forEach() method because it's less lines of code but for the sake of knowledge, here is how to do it using a for-loop.

```
const copyBtns = document.querySelectorAll(".copy-btn");
const htmlCodes = document.querySelectorAll(".html-code");

for (let i = 0; i < copyBtns.length; i++) {
  copyBtns[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
    htmlCodes[i].select();
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(htmlCodes[i].value);
  }) 
}
```